# Instruments showing a leak but no Object

Tags: iphone, memory, memory-leaks, instruments

I can see a Red line below in Leaks, but nothing in the call tree. AM I doing anything wrong?[image]

Comment: hard to know if we have only this screenshot.

Comment: use command + shift + b to track location of leaks in project

Answer (score 0):

You have selected call tree. select Leaks... Even after this you don't see anything ... Please 
provide that screen shot.

Comment: The screenshot is attached with the original post. I still cant see the leaking object